# Retrieve data efficiently using Firebase database in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app currently lets the user register his/her name, email, username, and password into the Firebase database. It creates a child: Users, which is then split into unique id's containing all the information for each id. Ex: Users -> [uniqueID] -> name, email....

I need help finding a way so that when the user enters their email and logs in, it will try to match it with any of the emails in the user's section of the database to see if it is valid. so like

```
if (listOfEmails.contains(emailLogin.getText().toString()) {

}
```

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but it would be worth considering using Firebase UI Auth to do the authentication, rather than writing all the code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is to use 
[Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/).

Than to verify if a user exists, create a new node in your Firebase database named `usersEmail`. Every time a user wants to sign-in, add his/her email address there. Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    ---- usersEmail
       |
       ---- userId1: "john@email.com"
       |
       ---- userId2: "mary@email.com"
       |
       ---- userId3: "mark@email.com"
       |
       //and so on
```

Hope it helps.